# Join Oracle Xquery

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery, xquery-sql

I have a Oracle table with a XML field and another table which contains a list of TAG which I need to find on first table. On second table I have another field to remap TAGs. The second table may have also null values.

Example:

Table1

| MY_XML |
| --- |
| `<TAG1>1</TAG1><TAG2>2</TAG2><TAG3>3</TAG3>` |

Table2

| XML_TAG_NAME | XML_NEW_TAG_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| TAG1 | NEW_TAG1 |
| null | null |
| TAG3 | NEW_TAG3 |

the result which I need should be:

```
<NEW_TAG1>1</NEW_TAG1><NEW_TAG_3>3</NEW_TAG_3>
```

I was trying with Xquery but I got lost. I don't know how to join data from both tables and how to exclude null values from Table2

```sql
select * from Table1 t
join  XMLTable('
    for $x in //descendant::*
    for $i in fn:collection("oradb:/MY_USER/TABLE2")/ROW
    
    
    return $i'
    passing case when t.MY_XML is null then null else xmltype ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>'||t.MY_XML)end
    ) on 1=1;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Does the table2 just have a list of tags and what they'd need to be transformed into, and this is common across all rows in table1? Why does the (presumably) TAG2 row in table2 have null in both columns? How is the database supposed to know that that row actually matches to TAG2 in table1?

Comment: I need to make a mapping, having an XML where I need to rename TAGs of table1 with TAGs of table2. Table2 has more columns which I omitted in example (that's why both columns can be null)

Comment: you need to update your question to provide a test case that has the minimum amount of data that demonstrates your actual issue. What happens if there's two rows in table1? Do the rows in table2 apply to both table1 rows, or is there some other way of mapping from table2 to table1?

Also, your xml isn't valid (there's no root node).